# Python 3.7 - Passing parameters to DLL using ctypes

Tags: python, double, ctypes

I have the following code:

```
num1=10.1234
int1=10
ret=GetOutput(int1,num1)
```

The function GetOutput is defined as

```
def GetOutput(int2, num2):
  lib = ctypes.WinDLL("mydllname.dll")
  prototype = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 4096))
  paramflags = (1, "int2",), (1, "num2",),
  GetOutput = prototype(("GetOutput", lib), paramflags)    
  ret=GetOutput(int2, num2)
  return ret
```

i get the following error and I am requesting your kind help.

```
LP_c_double_Array_4096 instance instead of float
```

If I convert num1 as:

```
num1=list(range(4096))
int1=10
ret=GetOutput(int1,num1)
```

I get the following error:

```
LP_c_double_Array_4096 instance instead of list
```

if I convert the num1 into array as follows:

```
num1=list(range(4096))
int1=10        
for item in num1:
    arrayA = array("i", num1)
ret=GetOutput(int1,arrayA)
```

i get the following errors:

```
<class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_double_Array_4096 instance instead of array.array
```

Please explain as much as possible as I am new to programming and only have very preliminary/basic understanding of OOPS, lists, tuples, pointers etc and no clue about ctypes.

Thanks

Comment: ctypes can be a little confusing. Are you actually trying to listen to a _callback_ function from you DLL (using `WINFUNCTYPE`)? It seems like you don't actually want to do that, as usually you'd pass a _function_ to the `WINFUNCTYPE` object. Can you confirm the signature of `lib.GetOutput`?

Comment: What is the C definition of `GetOutput` and what does it do?

Comment: Note: just to avoid confusion don't use the same name (*GetOutput*) for both functions.

Comment: Thank you all for asking further questions. It made me think and only now I realise that I did not understand the syntax correctly. Briefly, there are two functions and one structure name, all of which are written as "GetOutput". Only the structure needs to be "GetOutput"  and the functions can have any other name.  I have no way of testing it now from outside office as the code is on a PC connected to an instrument in my office. Will test it out and let you know. Background: I want to send commands to instrument and collect the data from its sensor. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, the following code is working - I have made a mistake in understanding what the dll is doing.

num2 is not an input but an output and hence the paramflags would change. Doing this allows any arbitrary declaration of num1.Since paramflags changed, calling the function Getoutput_Sub requires only one input now. Previously, I got confused by using the same function name.

```
num1=10.1234
int1=10
ret=GetOutput_Main(int1,num1)
```

The above is where the function is being called and the below is how the function is defined

```
def GetOutput_Main(int2, num2):
    lib = ctypes.WinDLL("mydllname.dll")
    prototype=ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 4096))
    paramflags = (1, "int2",), (2, "num2",),
    GetOutput_Sub = prototype(("GetOutput", lib),paramflags)    
    ret=GetOutput_Sub(int2)
    return ret
```

In my comment earlier, I said two functions and a structure. It is actually three functions; two that I am writing and one function (passing a string in quotes) that is standard for the dll.

Comment: This still doesn't look quite right. Is it possible to post the C function signature?

Comment: sorry, I do not know how to do that. you are asking for dict/help of something ?

Comment: No, the dll is provided by equipment manufacturer. Manual is provided about functions and variables.

Comment: Please see this discussion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367453/accessing-contents-of-an-object-returned-by-dll-using-ctypes-in-python

Comment: Function:  int Getoutput 
( 
Int    Int2 ;
Double*  Num2 
) 
 
Parameters:  
int2: with description of what it is;
num2: with description of what it is ;
 
Return:  
On success:  “Success message”;
On error:  “type of error”